# bootstrap anchor tag breaking column layout?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

With Bootstrap 4, when I include a hyperlink `<a>` tag in the middle column, it reduces the spacing of the leftmost column significantly(!) Only happens with `<a>` tags.

Very strange problem! Happens in different situations. Google returns nothing... any ideas? Thanks!

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <img style="display:block; width:35%; margin:auto;" src="/images/logo.png"  />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <p>Section title</p>
        <p>Section text</p>
        <a href="http://website.com">Visit website</a>
    </div>      
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] where this happens? When I try this, the results are not satisfying (i.e. there is no difference in column widths when adding or removing the <a>).

Comment: I can't reproduce this either. Here's a fiddle you can use: https://jsfiddle.net/8f78xeq4/

Comment: Thank you both I can't reproduce it in the fiddle so there must be something weird happening with other css, I'll update if I find it!

Comment: Fixed. So embarrassing, there was an unmatched <a> much higher on the page... so adding the <a></a> in the div made most of the page a link and broke the layout.